# Can not access some url with jest-cucumber

Tags: e2e-testing, cucumberjs, jest-puppeteer

I am using some simple code to implement e2e testes with `jest-cucumber`.

```
export const givenOpenUrl = (given) => {
  given(/^I open "(.*)"$/, async (arg0) => {
    await page.goto(`${arg0}`)
  })
}

export const thenMatchPageTitle = (then) => {
  then(/^I see "(.*)" in the title$/, async (arg0) => {
    await expect(page.title()).resolves.toMatch(arg0)
  })
}
```

Also this code fails as well :

```
describe('Nozzle AI', () => {
  beforeAll(async () => {
    await page.goto('https://nozzle.ai', {waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded'});

  });

  it('should be titled "Nozzle"', async () => {
    
    await expect(page.title()).resolves.toMatch('Nozzle');
  });
});
```

However, I get different behaviors based on the URL that is passed.
For example, the tests are passing if I use `https://www.google.com/` and failing when I use `https://www.nozzle.ai/` with the following error:

```
Navigation failed because the browser has disconnected!
```

It seems that the `page.title().resolve` has this error:

`Expected an Error, but "" was thrown`

I noticed that I am able to run this code with success :

```
(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://nozzle.ai', {
    waitUntil: 'networkidle2',
  });
  const title = await page.title()
  console.log(title)

  await browser.close();
})()
```

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated!

Comment: have you tried with any other url? you can even try with stackoverflow

Comment: stackoverflow works!